# lagom configuration override

Tags: docker, kubernetes, lagom

Is there any way to deploy lagom projects on kubernetes in different environments (ie. dev,stage,prod) such that I can use one image with multiple configuration overrides?

For example, let's say I have an environment variable, `foo=bar-{{env}}`. I want to build and publish one image and override configurations so that in dev `foo=bar-dev` and in prod `foo=bar-prod`.

Currently, my understanding is that the `application.conf` is tied to the image and cannot be overridden. If this is correct, is there a way to work around this so that I do not need to create multiple images, one for each environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a few ways:

**Static:**

You can create 3 deployments in 3 namespaces and add the env variable to each deployment. You can manage  these variables manually for each deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  namespace: dev
  name: envar-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: java-demo-container
    image: my-super-java-app
    env:
    - name: foo
      value: "bar-dev"
    - name: JAVA_HOME
      value: "/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java"
```

**Helm**:

You can make helm chart and use 3 files with variables to deploy your application.
To develop charts, you could read the [official documentation](https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide/#the-chart-template-developer-s-guide) or find some examples in [official Kubernetes repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can set typesafe config system property variable to override application.conf file

- application.conf: default conf file use in development

  > ```
  > foo: bar-dev
  > ```
- application.prod.conf:

  > ```
  > include "application.conf"
  > foo: bar-prod
  > ```

Set dockerfile system variable:

```
 ENTRYPOINT java -Dconfig.resource="$CONFIG_FILE"
```

In kubernetes yml

```
 env:
     - name: CONFIG_FILE
       value: "application.prod.conf"
```